# How can I make my title TopAppBar change after selecting a List Item

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[This is the screenshot of the Top part not changing after a list item is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0rZE.png)
Am trying to implement the method of Changing the TopAppBar when an item is selected from a list. I followed the same process as the MDSELECTIONLIST documentation. But still noting happens. So please I need help. Any help is appreciated.

```
        self.layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.up_layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, .12))
        self.low_layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', adaptive_height=True)
        self.scroll = MDScrollView()

        self.top_bar = MDTopAppBar(
            title='HOME SCREEN',
            pos_hint={'top': 1},
            elevation=0,
            right_action_items=[['plus', lambda touch: self.firstcontainer(touch)]]
        )

        self.up_layout.add_widget(self.top_bar)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.up_layout)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.scroll)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.selection_list = MDSelectionList(
            spacing="12dp",
            overlay_color=self.overlay_color[:-1] + [.2],
            on_selected=self.on_selected,
            on_unselected=self.on_unselected,
            on_selected_mode=self.set_selection_mode
        )

        self.scroll.add_widget(self.selection_list)  # Add MDSelectionList to the scroll view

        self.load_notes()  # Load notes initially

    def load_notes(self):
        self.selection_list.clear_widgets()  # Clear existing notes
        for key in self.store.keys():
            note_data = self.store.get(key)
            title = note_data["title"]
            body = note_data["body"]

            note_item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(
                text=str(title),
                secondary_text=str(body),
                _no_ripple_effect = True
            )
            note_item.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon="apple"))
            self.selection_list.add_widget(note_item)  # Add note_item to MDSelectionList

    def firstcontainer(self, touch):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        sm = app.root
        sm.current = 'second_screen'

    def on_selected(self, instance_selection_list, instance_selection_item):
        sm = App.get_running_app().root  # Access the ScreenManager
        first_screen = sm.get_screen('first_screen')  # Get the FirstScreen instance
        first_screen.top_bar.title = str(len(instance_selection_list.get_selected_list_items()))
    
    def on_unselected(self, instance_selection_list, instance_selection_item):
        sm = App.get_running_app().root  # Access the ScreenManager
        first_screen = sm.get_screen('first_screen')  # Get the FirstScreen instance
        first_screen.top_bar.title = str(len(instance_selection_list.get_selected_list_items()))


    def set_selection_mode(self, instance_selection_list, mode):
        if mode:
            md_bg_color = self.overlay_color
            left_action_items = [["close", lambda x: self.selection_list.unselected_all()]]
            right_action_items = [["trash-can"], ["dots-vertical"]]
        else:
            md_bg_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
            left_action_items = [["menu"]]
            right_action_items = [["magnify"], ["dots-vertical"]]
            sm = App.get_running_app().root
            first_screen = sm.get_screen('first_screen')
            first_screen.top_bar.title = "HOME SCREEN"
            Animation(md_bg_color=md_bg_color, d=0.2).start(first_screen.top_bar)
            self.top_bar.left_action_items = left_action_items
            self.top_bar.right_action_items = right_action_items
```